# Code working in all top browsers except IE

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to change text of a couple elements and animate the transition. Its tested as working in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. The problem is it has no effect in IE. Is there any code I should use instead of or in addition to what I have so far?

```
$('.overlay').on("click",function(){
    $('#category, #description').stop(true)

    var text = $(this).attr("data-title");

    $('#category').animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000, function () {
       $(this).text(text);
    }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000); 

    var info = $(this).attr("data-text");

    $('#description').animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000, function () {
       $(this).text(info);
    }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: That's because IE is'nt a top browser ?

Comment: Which jQuery version? They stopped supporting many versions of IE in version 2.0. And as darkajax said, which IE version?

Comment: @darkajax I tried it in IE 9

Comment: @Dave jquery.min 1.7.1

Comment: You should update to the latest version then, for a start (1.9.1 is the official latest release for supporting old IE). Before 1.8, vendor prefixes weren't applied, which could be your issue.

Comment: You say `no effect`, but have you checked if the `click` handler is executed at all in IE? Try adding `alert('foo')` at the beginning of the handler and see if the prompt appears in IE. Also, have you checked if there are any JS errors in IE?

Comment: @Dave I just did but it didn't help

Comment: He didn't intend for it to help, he asked if it alerted you or not.

Comment: @Boaz that looks to be the issue. The click handler isn't executed. I'm very new to js and jquery. How can I correct this?

Comment: @joeframbach I think you're confusing the comments and frankly your comment does nothing to help the situation

Comment: @Chrismo16 Where in your code are you binding the handler? Is it after page load within a `$(document).ready(...)` declaration?

Comment: @Boaz its in a custom.js that has all of the code within a jQuery(document).ready(function() {}

Comment: Is that `custom.js` included before or after the jQuery files? Also, are there any JS errors in the browser?

Comment: @Boaz I am getting a js error on the page from jquery.isotope.min.js but I'm not sure if its related to this section of the page. I'm using a template and not sure what isotope is used for but I'm looking into it now

Comment: @Boaz yes it is after the Jquery files

Comment: Your problem isn't in the code you posted, so can you create a minimal script which shows the problem? This is a good online tool; http://jsfiddle.net/ just write code which shows the behaviour, Save, and post the URL in your question. Remember to keep it minimal; nobody wants to hunt through pages of code.